# Webpack: TypeError default is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

Have some code that was previously compiled via `Browserify` / `Gulp` and that worked fine. However we are not switching to Webpack. The compilation of assets are working ok. They are written to disk, in the correct folder etc..

But this is causing a `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , h.default) is not a function` when visiting the page in the Browser.

The app is a basic React app..

Here is the Webpack config file...

```
const { join } = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'assets/javascript/bundle': './javascripts/bootstrap_app.js',
    'assets/stylesheets/all': './stylesheets/all.scss'
  },
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/build'
  },
  context: join(__dirname, 'client'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: './fonts'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|gif|jpeg|jpg|svg|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: './assets/images'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'resolve-url-loader',
          'sass-loader?sourceMap',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'views/index.handlebars',
      filename: 'views/index.handlebars'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    })
  ]
};
```

And my `.babelrc` file..

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["rewire"]
    },
    "test-cov": {
      "plugins": ["istanbul", "rewire"]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    "transform-function-bind",
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
}
```

When running `"build": "./node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js --config ./webpack.config.js --display-error-details",` everything compiles ok. There are no error messages.

But when opening up my browser, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , h.default) is not a function
```

Stack Trace

```
bundle.js:172 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , h.default) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:172)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:172)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:172)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:106)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:106)
    at n (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
```

when clicking on the first error message..the error occurs somewhere around...

`window.jQuery=u.default,(0,h.default)(u.default);`

Comment: `default` is a reserved word, don't use it.

Comment: That's the error output. `Default` isn't used anywhere

Comment: Can you post the entire error with he stack trace?

Comment: looks like you are exporting named export as default one, but need to see the code

Comment: I've included the stack trace. The code hasn't changed at all. It compiled fine with Webpack. No errors. Just runtime error. Those runtime errors were not there with using Browserify

Comment: try removing Uglify for a while and add source-maps to see readable stack trace

Comment: ok giving it a try